# How to offset the memory location indicated by an object in C++

Tags: c++

I have this implementation in C#.

If I am not wrong, it is used to: offsetting the memory location indicated by allocatedObject by size number of bytes and converting the memory pointer to an Int64

```
short size = getSize();

IntPtr allocatedObject;

long posInMemory = allocatedObject.Offset(size).ToInt64();
```

How can I achieve this in C++: the position in memory of the IntPtr (`void *allocatedObject;`) and convert the memory pointer to an Int64.

Comment: That seems super dangerous.  What are you doing that could need this?

Comment: There's very little reason to grab stuff from random areas of memory in C++, don't do that unless programming microcontrollers.

Comment: It seems, what we have here is an OP who doesn't know what he is doing, and he is asking "can I haz" to translate C# to C++ for him - but without showing the full code and spreading the question over 3 misguided X/Y problem questions. Sweet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have an `int64_t` type that represents a 64bits integer, you would first cast the pointer to a pointer to `char` (that by definition has `sizeof = 1`), then offset it by the size, then cast it again to a pointer to `int64_t`.

```
static_cast< int64_t* >( static_cast< char* >( allocatedObject ) + size )
```

That's because you cannot do pointer arithmetics with a `void` pointer, as it has no size. Alternatively, you could `reinterpret_cast` the pointer to a `std::intptr_t` (an integer big enough to contain any pointer), increase it by size and then cast to pointer to  `int64_t`.

Comment: why not just `(int64_t*)(allocatedObject + size)` ?

Comment: @Abyx: Because C-style casts are the scum of the earth?

Comment: @DeadMG, so you prefer to use `manyletters_cast` when you cast an integer to pointer?

Comment: @Abyx: Well, you are not getting charged by the number of letters in the identifier, and it gives you the safety of failing to compile if you somehow messed either the integer or the pointer... Worth the few extra chars to avoid having to seek a mysterious bug.

Comment: @K-ballo, btw, if `allocatedObject` is IntPtr, you need an `reinterpret_cast` there

Comment: @Abyx: `allocatedObject` is `void*`, check the question

Comment: @Abyx: If you care to read the question, the OP specifies that what its an `IntPtr` in his C# its a `void*` in his C++

Comment: @K-ballo, sorry, I see it now.

Comment: @K-ballo but what I need is the position of a string in memory (long posInMemory) it is not: int64_t*